# How do I sign an apk for play store?

Tags: java, android, module-packaging

I have signed an app in adroid studio and made it an APK but cannot install on devices. App works fine on my emulator but cannot install on devices.

Haven't tried any solution yet.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to add more details such as if you get any errors etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you should do before installing a release version of your project on a device:

**First:** Make sure you build a signed apk when building your project.
**Second:** Make sure you tick both checkboxes while signing your apk. I.e v1 and v2 as the latter one is not supported on older android versions.
**Third:** Make sure you've enabled installs from untrusted sources on the devices you're trying to installs on.

I hope this helps :)